# Bluetooth API, if I can send left and right channels of a stereo sound to two seperate devices?

Tags: bluetooth

I tried to check the documentations but I could not find the answer. Any comment would be much appreciated.

Using either Native Mobile Bluetooth APIs (IOS or Android) or Web Bluetooth API, can I connect to two bluetooth speaker devices(ex: two seperate headphones), and send LEFT and RIGHT channels of a stereo sound to these two devices seperately in sync with each other?

Comment: Let’s put it this way; nope ;) That said, if your interested in how True Wireless products out there today are designed in HW/FW and Bluetooth interoperability aspects, there are ways to achieve what you’re looking for — but in the Bluetooth specs there’s no support to split an audio stream from a *source* to two different *sinks*.

Comment: Rumors whisper that Bluetooth 5.1 spec however might have something for you... but we’re not there yet ;)

Comment: Have a look at Qualcomm; https://www.qualcomm.com/news/releases/2018/02/21/qualcomm-broadcast-audio-helps-users-stream-music-numerous-bluetooth